# Crystal report SQL command over 8000 characters

Tags: crystal-reports

I have multiple complex SQL queries (each SQL is less than 8,000 characters). Each SQL will return about 5 rows. In database, I can easily use UNION to put all SQL queries into 1 query, and then sort the result in that 1 query.

But now I cannot create anything in database. This has to be done in Crystal report, and Crystal report only allow 8,000 characters SQL command.

How can I deal with this 8,000 characters limitation? I know sub-reports can pass value to main report. But I don't know how to merge multiple sub-reports result and then sort them.

Comment: Can you add one of the sql here so we can inspect the code? For example if you use MSSQL you could use one or more CTEs (common table expression) once and reuse the code in queries below. Another option is get your DBA to create a view which standardizes and simplifies your query for later use. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Those SQL code don't have many in common. Each of them will query different tables, using different filters. So can't build reusable codes (like CTE) to make the whole query shorter. And we can't do anything on database, no DBA's help. Everything has to be done in Crystal Reports

Comment: Bit of a late comment, sorry, but I don;t think there is a limit of 8000 characters in Crystal Reports for a SQL command. I've tried Crystal Reports 2008 with no issue. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using Crystal Reports XI R2. The size limit is 64K, it's around 8000 characters.